# Facebook Invalid Key hash

Tags: android, facebook

I created the key hash by the following command:

> keytool -exportcert -alias mykey -keystore keystore | openssl
>   sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Or:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.company.appname",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Both returned the same key hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=, the last letter is "=". I configure it in my application in Facebook.

[image]

The appid, display name,package name and class name are all correct. But I still got the Invalid Key Hash problem.

[image]

But the key hash displayed in the error message doesn't have the "=". Is this the cause of the problem? Or is there anything else I should know? Thanks

Comment: this is right way toget hash key . It may be you copied wrong. try it again

Comment: Use both android key store  and the you app key store (used for Signing the APK) to get key hash and store both key hash on fb.

Comment: I found the problem. That because I have another testing program with the same package name. But the issue now is it always point to my testing program even I change the package name of my testing app and use my correct app id.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix :You can copy that Invalid key Hash  and add "=" to Key Hashes in setting app on facebook.

Comment: My key is correct in Facebook settings. The problem I guess is the Facebook sdk cached the old app id in application. I tested in a new Android phone without problem.